# Magento2 how to display shipping methods in Dropdown field in checkout page instead of radio button

Tags: magento2.3.0

How can I display shipping methods in the dropdown field in checkout page?

Comment: It may be useful for you , its convert by jQuery https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Checkbox-Radio-Inputs-To-Dropdown-jQuery.html

Comment: @payal did you got the solution how to convert shipping methods radio to dropdown ?